# ServiceStack AutoQuery and [Authenticate] Attribute

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth, servicestack-autoquery

I'd like to enforce authentication on some auto querys.

```
[Authenticate]
public class BusinessEntitiesService : QueryDb<DataModel.dbo.BusinessEntity>
{
}
```

Here's my issue. The above class is in my ServiceModel project... in order to add the [Authenticate] attribute, I need to add a reference to ServiceStack.dll which I think can cause issues down the road (according to previous guidance to only reference ServiceStack.Interfaces in the ServiceModel). I can't add the above class to ServiceInterfaces because then I'd have to reference that everywhere I use the client.

I've also tried using a GlobalRequestFilter... but that appears to goof with the AdminFeature plugin:

```
    private bool IsAProtectedPath(string path)
    {
        return !path.StartsWith("/auth") && !path.StartsWith("/autoquery");
    }

        GlobalRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
        {
            if(IsAProtectedPath(httpReq.PathInfo))
                new AuthenticateAttribute().Execute(httpReq, httpResp, requestDto);
        });
```

[image]

Not really sure how to best handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to apply the `[Authenticate]` attribute to AutoQuery Services you would need to create a [custom AutoQuery implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/AutoQuery-RDBMS#custom-autoquery-implementations) and apply your Filter attributes on that, e.g:

```
[Authenticate]
public class MyProtectedAutoQueryServices : Service 
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

    public object Any(QueryBusinessEntity query) =>
        AutoQuery.Execute(query, AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, Request));

    public object Any(QueryBusinessEntity2 query) =>
        AutoQuery.Execute(query, AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, Request));
}
```

An alternative is to dynamically add attributes to your AutoQuery Request DTO, but these would need to be registered before `Configure()` is called, either before `appHost.Init()` or in your AppHost constructor, e.g:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost()
    {
        typeof(QueryBusinessEntity)
            .AddAttributes(new AuthenticateAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is IAutoQueryDb supposed to be injected into Service? I'm getting a null exception on it.... using basically the same example from the link you provided.

Comment: @ChrisKlepeis Yeah `IAutoQueryDb` is registered in the IOC when you register the AutoQueryFeature, e.g `Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature());`